# How can I use a array inside a include()

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have a Spreadsheet with around 300 different URL's. I have a second Sheet within that Spreadsheet that has around 50 domains in it. The idea is that the script scans every URL and checks whether the domain exists in the domains list. If the domain exists give me the total number of domains that are found. This last part is working.

But the problem is that the list of domains changes from 10 to about 90. So today it's 50 but next week it could be 85. I don't want to write 85 if statements.

I was thinking about what if I can place an array inside the includes() but I couldn't get that to work.

```
if(backlink.includes(startpaginaRows[])){
  startpaginaCount++;
}
```

This is my script:

```
function backlinkAnalyse() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var backlinks = ss.getSheetByName("Backlinks").activate();
  var backlinksRows = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var startpagina = ss.getSheetByName("Types").activate();
  var lastRow = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var lastRow = lastRow.filter(String).length;
  var startpaginaRows = ss.getRange("A2:A"+lastRow).getValues();
  
  var startpaginaCount = 1;
  
  var filteredRows = backlinksRows.filter(function(row){
    var backlink = row[1];
    if(backlink != ""){
      if(backlink.includes("startpagina.nl")){
        startpaginaCount++;
      }
      else if(backlink.includes("startkabel.nl")){
        startpaginaCount++;
      }
      else if(backlink.includes("goedbegin.nl")){
        startpaginaCount++;
      }
    }
  })
  var startpPaginaCount = startpaginaCount - 1;
  ss.getSheetByName("Linkprofiel").activate();
  ss.getRange("B2").setValue(startpaginaCount);
}
```

Comment: If this is going to be an established project. Make sure you optimize your code. You declare many variables that you don't use anywhere: `backlinksRows`, `backlinks`, `startpagina`. **Also**, the accepted solution does not take advantage of the sheet you have all the unique websites. Instead, he defines a hard copy array of urls which is not maintanable at all and does not make use of the `Types` sheet. If you want to take advantage of the `Types` sheet and you don't want to manually update the `backlinkPossibilites` array, check my answer.

Comment: Hi Marios, Thanks for your replay. I removed all the unused variables, thanks for that. In terms of the array. I changed the code like this: ```var backlinkPossibilites = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();```. So the array is made up from the values that or in the ```Types``` sheet. Once I'm home I'll look into your suggestion, it looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) checks in a [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) loop and save an array of possible matches ahead of time:

```js
function backlinkAnalyse() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var backlinks = ss.getSheetByName("Backlinks").activate();
  var backlinksRows = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var startpagina = ss.getSheetByName("Types").activate();
  var lastRow = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var lastRow = lastRow.filter(String).length;
  var startpaginaRows = ss.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow).getValues();
  var startpaginaCount = 1;
  var filteredRows = backlinksRows.filter(function(row) {
    var backlink = row[1];
    var backlinkPossibilites = ["startpagina.nl", "startkabel.nl", "goedbegin.nl"];
    if (backlink != "") {
      if (backlinkPossibilites.some(function(pos) {
          return backlink.includes(pos);
        })) {
        startpaginaCount++;
      }
    }
  });
  var startpPaginaCount = startpaginaCount - 1;
  ss.getSheetByName("Linkprofiel").activate();
  ss.getRange("B2").setValue(startpaginaCount);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you want to check if the values in `startpaginaRows` are included in some of the `backlink` string and you can do it this way:

```
var filteredRows = backlinksRows.filter(function(row){
    var backlink = row[1];
    if(backlink != ""){
      if(startpaginaRows.some((row) => backlink.includes(row))){
        startpaginaCount++;
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

### Is there any particular reason you don't use a simple google sheet formula?

`=COUNTIFS(Backlinks!$A:$A,Types!$A:$A,Backlinks!$A:$A,A1)`

### Output:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to find out whether the arrays `backlink` and `startpaginaRows` intersect.

```js
const backlink = ["a", "b", "c"];
const startpaginaRows = ["c", "d", "e"];

const doTheyIntersect = backlink.map(link => startpaginaRows.includes(link)).reduce((a, b) => a || b, false);

if(doTheyIntersect) {
  console.log("They intersect");
}
```